# How to check from API if the email is registered

Tags: javascript, json, api

app.js

```
client.request
      .get(
        'https://url.dev/api/users/${email}',
        options
      )
      .then(
        data => {
          const userInfo = JSON.parse(data.response).data
          if (data.ok) {
            var name = userInfo.name;
            var initials = name.charAt(0);
            document.getElementById("nameInitial").innerHTML = initials;
            document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = name;
            document.getElementById("email").innerHTML = userInfo.email;
           }
          else {
            var name = "Unknown";
            var initials = name.charAt(0);
            document.getElementById("nameInitial").innerHTML = initials;
            document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = name;
            document.getElementById("email").innerHTML = "Unknown"
          }
          
        },
          error => {
            console.error('An error occurred during the request..');
            console.error(error);
          }
      );
```

what i am trying to do is to handle error if the email is not registered on the URL that I try to GET request. When the email is not register yet and return code 404, it will not display as I set in `else`.

`console.log(data.ok)` showed code 200 in console if I append registered email on URL, but if I append unregistered email, I will get this in console:

```
Object
attempts: 1
errorSource: "APP"
headers: {date: "Tue, 19 Apr 2021 05:41:27 GMT", content-type: "application/json", transfer-encoding: "chunked", connection: "close", set-cookie: Array(1), …}
response: "{\n    \"message\": \"\"\n}"
status: 404
```

I do not know why it did not display as I want if the email is not registered and response code is 404.

Answer (score 0):

How this works:
GET request URL exists => 200 OK
GET request URL doesn't exist => 404 not found
Your name is not registered yet and the associated URL doesn't exist.
So the programs skips the else block in favour of error block.
My opinion: I would redo the API appropriately (the name should be a parameter)